# How To: Closure Template for generating HTML in which attribute value of an element contains curly braces

Tags: templates, google-closure

How do I get following HTML created using closure template?

```
<input name="fullName" class="large" type="text" data-validate="{required:true, minlength: 5, maxlength:100, messages:{required:'Please provide your Full Name.', maxlength:'This field can contain maximum 100 characters.'}}"/>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Below is what I have tried till now.

```
{namespace myApp.test}
/**
 * Template for UI of Create User View 
 * @param userToEdit It is the object returned from GET on User Resource.
 */
{template .testUser autoescape="false"}
  {{msg desc="<input id=\"fullName\" name=\"fullName\" class=\"large\" type=\"text\" value=\"{$userToEdit.FullName}\" data-validate=\"{required:true, minlength: 5, maxlength:100, messages:{required:\'Please provide your Full Name.\', maxlength:\'This field can contain maximum 100 characters.\'} }\" />"}}
{/template}
```

Returns `Malformed attributes in tag` error.

---

```
{namespace myApp.test}
/**
 * Template for UI of Create User View 
 * @param userToEdit It is the object returned from GET on User Resource.
 */
{{template .testUser autoescape="false"}}
<input id="fullName" name="fullName" class="large" type="text" value="{{$userToEdit.FullName}}" data-validate="{required:true, minlength: 5, maxlength:100, messages:{required:'Please provide your Full Name.', maxlength:'This field can contain maximum 100 characters.'} }" />
{{/template}}
```

Return `Tag 'template' not at start of line [line 6, column 1].` error.

---

```
{namespace myApp.test}
/**
 * Template for UI of Create User View 
 * @param userToEdit It is the object returned from GET on User Resource.
 */
{template .testUser autoescape="false"}
<input id="fullName" name="fullName" class="large" type="text" value="{$userToEdit.FullName}" data-validate="{required:true, minlength: 5, maxlength:100, messages:{required:'Please provide your Full Name.', maxlength:'This field can contain maximum 100 characters.'} }" />
{/template}
```

Returns `template .testUser: Left brace '{' not allowed within a Soy tag delimited by single braces (consider using double braces to delimit the Soy tag) [line 7, column 164].` error.

---

```
{namespace myApp.test}
/**
 * Template for UI of Create User View 
 * @param userToEdit It is the object returned from GET on User Resource.
 */
{template .testUser autoescape="false"}
<input id="fullName" name="fullName" class="large" type="text" value="{$userToEdit.FullName}" data-validate="{{required:true, minlength: 5, maxlength:100, messages:{{required:'Please provide your Full Name.', maxlength:'This field can contain maximum 100 characters.'}} }}" />
{/template}
```

Returns `template .testUser: Double left brace '{{' not allowed within a Soy tag delimited by double braces (consider inserting a space: '{ {') [line 7, column 165].` error.

---

```
{namespace myApp.test}
/**
 * Template for UI of Create User View 
 * @param userToEdit It is the object returned from GET on User Resource.
 */
{template .testUser autoescape="false"}
<input id="fullName" name="fullName" class="large" type="text" value="{$userToEdit.FullName}" data-validate="{{required:true, minlength: 5, maxlength:100, messages:{ {required:'Please provide your Full Name.', maxlength:'This field can contain maximum 100 characters.'} } }}" />
{/template}
```

Returns `template myApp.test.testUser: Not all code is in Soy V2 syntax (found tag {{print required:true, minlength: 5, maxlength:100, messages:{ {required:'Please provide your Full Name.', maxlength:'This field can contain maximum 100 characters.'} } }} not in Soy V2 syntax).` error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [Literal Command](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/docs/commands.html#literal) worked like a charm. Thanks to [Jim](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/closure-templates-discuss/MwtzLHJLd9s/s1_Uq3VXbU0J).

```
{namespace myApp.test}
/**
 * Template for UI of Create User View 
 * @param userToEdit It is the object returned from GET on User Resource.
 */
{template .testUser autoescape="false"}
<input name="fullName" value="{$userToEdit.FullName}" class="large" type="text" {literal}data-validate="{required:true, minlength: 5, maxlength:100, messages:{required:'Please provide your Full Name.', maxlength:'This field can contain maximum 100 characters.'}}"{/literal}/>
{/template}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the ["Special Characters" section in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/commands?csw=1#specialcharacters), `{lb}` and `{rb}` seem to be the way to go. These will add a left brace or right brace, respectively, to your output as plain text.